# Is there a way to apply chrome local overrides without opening dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I created a Chrome local override for a CSS file and it works fine but only after dev tools has been opened or is already open. I'm trying to get this local override to apply on page load without having to open dev tools. It does persist after dev tools is closed, but it needs to be opened first to apply the override. Is there a way to run dev tools on page load in the background or have the override automatically run on page load?

I looked through other override dev tool questions but couldn't find a straight answer. A lot of them say that it doesn't run if dev tools is closed, but my override is still applied after closing dev tools.

Comment: There's no way. The only alternative is to use an extension that implements such functionality. Note that devtools should be open only at the moment the resource is loaded, it doesn't have to be open afterwards.